# Why is my Maltego tranform giving me a empty value error?

Tags: python

I'm right now trying to code a Maltego tranform to search through the Breach Compilation data, using query.sh

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Maltego transform for grabbing Breach Compilation results locally.
from MaltegoTransform import *
import sys
import os
import subprocess
email = sys.argv[1]
mt = MaltegoTransform()
try:
    dataleak = subprocess.check_output("LOCATION OF QUERY.SH" + email, shell=True).splitlines()
    for info in dataleak:
        mt.addEntity('maltego.Phrase', info)
    else:
        mt.addUIMessage("")
except Exception as e:
    mt.addUIMessage(str(e))
mt.returnOutput()
```

> Empty value for @org.simpleframework.xml.Text(data=false,
>   required=true, empty=) on method 'value' in class
>   com.paterva.maltego.transform.protocol.v2api.messaging.TransformResponse$Notification
>   at line 26

Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Also, sorry for the typo. Pretty tired right now.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out

```
    else:
        mt.addUIMessage("")
except Exception as e:
    mt.addUIMessage(str(e))
```

that bit of code was the problem. Got it working just fine.